# Normal HTML page to access the SharePoint Online data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I would like to develop a  page to get the list data from SharePoint 2013(Office 365)

I try to get the data from REST API e.g.

```
String url="https://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Photo')/files"
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
string strOut = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

It will return the 403 error.

After my finding, I think I'm missing the access token, and the access token should be get from the SharePoint apps.

Anyone can tell me how can I get the access token.?

Is it mean I should create high trust app first, and let the page to call the app to get the access token??

Please let me know if the logic is wrong.

Comment: are you trying to do an app on Sharepoint 2013?

Comment: No , I am trying to connect SharePoint 2013 data from normal html page , maybe aspx / php etc.

Comment: Maybe you need to refer to the Request.aspx page that lives in Sharepoint otherwise you cannot get the data

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Managed code to access SharePoint Online via REST API, i would recommend you to utilize the [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585). It comes with a [SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) class that is intended for authenticating the user in SPO.

How to make a web request to SPO

```
var username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "password";
var webUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com";
var query = "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/files?$filter=Name eq 'Order.docx'";

//Construct SPO credentials 
var securedPassword = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);
//Make a request with SPO credentials
var request = WebRequest.Create(webUrl + query);            
request.Credentials = credentials;
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

//...
```